# App::environment not found with Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, environment

I have a file in one of my packages (Oauth2 Madewithlove package), where I have a function that I am using.  In this function, I want to use a certain Facebook App for my local environment and a certain for my production environment.  Therefore the function looks like this:

```
public function search($query = '', $type = '') {

        if(App::environment('local')) {
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?key=value&access_token=********|***************&q='.str_replace(' ', '+', $query).'&type='.$type;
        }
        else {
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?key=value&access_token=***********|*****************&q='.str_replace(' ', '+', $query).'&type='.$type;
        }

        return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    }
```

Where the starred out portions are the app ids and secrets.  However, when running this, I get the error:

```
Class 'OAuth2\Provider\App' not found
```

with the filepath:

```
/­vendor/­madewithlove/­laravel-oauth2/­src/­OAuth2/­Provider/­Facebook.php
```

This points to the App:environment line.  I have already added this to my config in the bootstrap/start.php file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('******-*******-MacBook-Pro.local'),

));
```

Any idea why I am getting the error?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
\App::environment();
```

Laravel is not namespaced, so every class will be in the root name space.  Since your class `Facebook` is in the `OAuth2\Provider` namespace, it looks for `OAuth2\Provider\App` unless you specify that it is in the root namespace with the leading `\`.

---

You can also fix this with [`use`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

```
<?php namespace OAuth2\Provider

// Imports use the root namespace
use App;

class Facaebook
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(App::environment());
    }

}
```

Comment: This was the issue.  Thank you.